# Why is this re-write rule in htaccess causing re-direct error?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've just changed hosts on my website, for some reason when i try and view it i'm getting "too many redirects" error. I've narrowed it down to a specific rule in my .htaccess file but i don't understand why this rule doesn't work on my new server?

This is the rule

```
RewriteRule ^games/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=games&console=$1 [NC,L]
```

Full htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on

    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>


ErrorDocument 404 /not-found/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]


RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^play/(.+)/?$ /index.php?page=play&console=$1 [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^games/([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=games&console=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: This rule won't cause `too many redirects`. Post your complete .htaccess and also tell for what URL do you get this error?

Comment: @anubhava added full htaccess, when i comment out the bottom line it works fine. If i remove comment i get too many redirects error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /not-found/
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^play/(.+)/?$ /index.php?page=play&console=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^games/([\w\s.-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=games&console=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Thanks i changed my line and added `([\w\s.-]+)` and it works so the issue seems to be with: `([A-Za-z0-9_-\s\.]+)` What is the other stuff you added?

Comment: `[A-Za-z0-9_-\s\.]` is wrong because of an unescaped hyphen in the middle of character class that acts as a range not just literal hyphen.